# setInterval doesn't work when trying to stop progress bar

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, setinterval

I have a simple progress bar function and I need to stop it when clicking on the stop button. This is my code -http://jsfiddle.net/ratpfwvd/ and setInterval doesn't seem to be working.

**html**

```
<div class="progress-bar"><div></div></div>

<button class="start">start</button>
<button class="stop">stop</button>
```

**css**

```
.progress-bar{
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
    background-color:blue;
}

div{
    height:100%;
    width:0;
    background-color:red;
  }
```

**script**

```
var resetProgressBar =   setInterval(progress, 8000);

function progress(percent, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 8000, function(f) {
        var progressBarWidth = 0;
        $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 0);
    });
}

$('.start').click(function(){
      progress(100, $('.progress-bar'));
}); 

$('.stop').click(function(){
        clearInterval(resetProgressBar); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for animation, you need to use [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$('.stop').click(function () {
    $('.progress-bar').find('div').stop()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8tudpeh5/)